# android:inputType="textUri" wont enable internet keyboard (w .com button)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyboard

I have an issue where I'm calling the internet keyboard with the .com button however it won't display when the keyboard is triggered.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:hint="@string/code_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:inputType="textUri" />
```

Comment: .com button just show in tablets not in android phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try giving the `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` to have the keyboard with .com button.

Comment: I did... no luck - still displays the same

Comment: which device or Emulator are you using?

Comment: Does it not appear on certain devices?

Comment: That may be the problem because i am using android:inputType="textEmailAddress" in my application and its showing .com button on my keyboard.

Comment: It's the device... I tried it in an emulator and it worked flawlessly. (Thanks!)